# Show that S is a subspace of ${R}^{2\times2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let **v**= (1,2)$^T$ be a given vector, and let $S$ = {$A$ ∈ ${ \mathbb{R} }^{2\times2}$ | **a**$_1$$\bot$**v**}. (I.e., $S$ is the set of all 2x2 real matrices with column 1 orthogonal to the given vector **v**.)

How do I show that $S$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{2\times2}$?

I know that in order for $S$ to be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{2\times2}$, $S$ has to satisfy the following conditions:

1. $S$ can not be an empty set.
2. If $s$ ∈ $S$ and $a$ is a scalar, then $as$ ∈ $S$.
3. If $s_1, s_2$ ∈ $S$, then $s_1 + s_2$ ∈ $S$.

I understand this much, but I have no idea how to go about showing that the following hold true in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's exactly what you must do.

1. The subspace is obviously not empty, e.g. 
   $$
       \begin{pmatrix}
       2 & x \\
       -1 & y  \\
       \end{pmatrix}
   $$ for any $x,y$.
2. and 3. I've already given you a hint for these two. Your matrices are characterised through the orthogonality of the first column with $$
      v= \begin{pmatrix}
       1  \\
       2   \\
       \end{pmatrix}
   $$
   You can derive from that the form of the column and then check if the sum and scalar product also lie in $S$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $A\in S$, it is easy to check that $A$ has the following format:

> $$A=\begin{bmatrix}2a&b\\-a&c\end{bmatrix},\ a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}.$$

Indeed,

> $$a_1^T\cdot v=\begin{bmatrix}2a&-a\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\end{bmatrix}=2a-2a=0\Rightarrow a_1\perp v.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: prove that, setting $e_1=(1,0)^T$,
$$
S=\{A\in\mathbb{R}^{2\times2}:v^T\!Ae_1=0\}$$

Now the zero matrix obviously belongs to $S$. If $A,B\in S$, then
$$
v^T(A+B)e_1=\dots
$$
Do similarly for $A\in S$ and a scalar $a$.

This is essentially the same as proving that the function
$$
f\colon \mathbb{R}^{2\times2}\to\mathbb{R},\qquad f(A)=v^T\!Ae_1
$$
is linear and $S=\ker f$.